# On algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

How to prove that $[\bar{\mathbb{Q}} : \mathbb{Q} ]$ = $\infty$?

Comment: Hint: If it was finite, what would that say about the possible degree of an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Answer (score 6):

**Hint** $\{ \sqrt{p} \}_{p \,  prime}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** $\left\{\sqrt[n]2\right\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ cannot be contained in a finitely generated extension.